# Meteor Installer giving error in windows 8

Tags: windows, meteor

I am getting this error after installing the meteor

> \AppData\Local.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.1.1\mt-os.windows.x86_32\
>   was unex pected at this time.

My environment variable for meteor is

> {{LocalUser}}\AppData\Local\ .meteor

Answer (score 0):

Did you use quotes around the Variable in the calling resource/script? Why are there brackets and curly braces around Local User part of environment variable? It is what is causing the error. If you really want to keep them quotes should make it so the error doesn't happen.

Comment: {{LocalUser}} is the user name which I don't want to show that is why used here.There is just user name no braces and all

Comment: Get in touch with the Meteor people I guess.